# Comparing 2 reports using same source

Tags: reporting-services, group-by, ssrs-2008

I am asked to create 2 reports one for Attendance by Main Course and other one Attendance by lecturer.

Both reports are using same datasource and dataset however the parameters and groups inside report are different.

My mgr says the totals should match in both the reports. I am not sure if that is possible. Kindly let me know.

```
Query1:

SELECT DISTINCT PrimaryProgramme, PRPH_Title, PRPH_ML1, Section, AgeBand, RegYear, Section_Name, REGT_Provision_Code, Student_ID, CourseType, Mins_Poss, Mins_Att, Mins_Late, TermTimeWeekNo, Surname, Forename, AttendanceMark, WeekStart, Class_Register COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT + ' - ' + Register_Title COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT + ' - ' + Register_Day COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT + '  ' + CONVERT(char(5), StartTime, 108) + ' - ' + CONVERT(char(5), EndTime, 108) AS Register
FROM            CurrentAttendance_New
WHERE        (AgeBand IN (@AgeBand)) AND (CourseType IN (@CourseType)) AND (RegYear = @Year)
ORDER BY PrimaryProgramme
```

[image: Report1]

```
Sample data:

                PrimaryProgramme    PRPH_Title  PRPH_ML1    Section AgeBand RegYear Section_Name    CourseType  Mins_Poss   Mins_Att    Mins_Late   Surname Forename    Register
                11017         Access to Nursing AP1 H+SC    19+ 2015    AP1 Health+Social Care**    FunctionalSkill 0   0   0   Cummings    Sornia  000018574 - English E3 FS Day (Pearson) - Monday  09:30 - 11:30
                11017         Access to Nursing AP1 H+SC    19+ 2015    AP1 Health+Social Care**    FunctionalSkill 0   0   0   Cummings    Sornia  000018587 - Maths E2 FS Day (Pearson) - Friday  09:30 - 11:30
                11017         Access to Nursing AP1 H+SC    19+ 2015    AP1 Health+Social Care**    FunctionalSkill 0   0   0   Dobson  Jodie   000018574 - English E3 FS Day (Pearson) - Monday  09:30 - 11:30
                11017         Access to Nursing AP1 H+SC    19+ 2015    AP1 Health+Social Care**    FunctionalSkill 60  60  60  Cummings    Sornia  000018574 - English E3 FS Day (Pearson) - Monday  09:30 - 11:30
                11017         Access to Nursing AP1 H+SC    19+ 2015    AP1 Health+Social Care**    FunctionalSkill 105 105 15  Cummings    Sornia  000018574 - English E3 FS Day (Pearson) - Monday  09:30 - 11:30
                11017         Access to Nursing AP1 H+SC    19+ 2015    AP1 Health+Social Care**    GCSE    0   0   0   Hyland   Brenda 000019736 - GCSE Maths Friday Day (Pearson) - Friday  11:00 - 13:30
                11017         Access to Nursing AP1 H+SC    19+ 2015    AP1 Health+Social Care**    GCSE    0   0   0   Pemberton   Charlotte   000019653 - GCSE English (AQA) Wed 9.30-12.00 - Wednesday  09:30 - 12:00
                11017         Access to Nursing AP1 H+SC    19+ 2015    AP1 Health+Social Care**    GCSE    0   0   0   Pemberton   Charlotte   000019736 - GCSE Maths Friday Day (Pearson) - Friday  11:00 - 13:30
                11017         Access to Nursing AP1 H+SC    19+ 2015    AP1 Health+Social Care**    GCSE    150 0   0   Lynes   Anne-Marie  000019655 - GCSE Maths Thu 6.30-9.00 (Pearson) - Thursday  18:30 - 21:00
                11017        Access to Nursing  AP1 H+SC    19+ 2015     AP1 Health+Social Care**   Main    0   0   0   Agyeiwaa Yaa    Maame   000018531 - Access To Nursing - Thursday  11:15 - 13:00
                11017        Access to Nursing  AP1 H+SC    19+ 2015     AP1 Health+Social Care**   Main    0   0   0   Burgin  Sarah   000018515 - Access To Nursing - Wednesday  09:30 - 11:00
               11017         Access to Nursing  AP1 H+SC    19+ 2015    AP1 Health+Social Care**    Main    0   0   0   Burgin  Sarah   000018537 - Access To Nursing - Thursday  13:45 - 15:15
              11017          Access to Nursing  AP1 H+SC    19+ 2015    AP1 Health+Social Care**    Main    0   0   0   Cummings    Sornia  000018497 - Access To Nursing - Tuesday  09:30 - 11:00
12647                   BTEC L1 Diploma for IT Users (ITQ) (Pearson)    AP2 INFT    1618    2015    AP2 Information Technology**    Addition    0   0   0   Eldridge    Tommy   000019207 - Employability - Tuesday  10:00 - 10:30
12647                   BTEC L1 Diploma for IT Users (ITQ) (Pearson)    AP2 INFT    1618    2015    AP2 Information Technology**    Addition    0   0   0   Fox Edward  000019207 - Employability - Tuesday  10:00 - 10:30
12647                   BTEC L1 Diploma for IT Users (ITQ) (Pearson)    AP2 INFT    1618    2015    AP2 Information Technology**    Addition    0   0   0   Hill    Kristopher  000019202 - Tutorial + Enrichment 1 Yr - Tuesday  09:00 - 10:00
12647                   BTEC L1 Diploma for IT Users (ITQ) (Pearson)    AP2 INFT    1618    2015    AP2 Information Technology**    Addition    0   0   0   Langley George  000017956 - Tutorial + Enrichment 1 Yr - Tuesday  09:00 - 10:00
```

[image: Report2]

```
Query 2:
    SELECT DISTINCT 
    Lecturer_Code, LecturerName, AgeBand, RegYear, PRPH_ML1, 
    [Curriculum Area], PRPH_Title, Section, Section_Name, 
    Class_Register COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT + ' - ' + 
    Register_Title COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT + ' - ' + Register_Day COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT + '  ' + CONVERT(char(5),
    StartTime, 108) + ' - ' + CONVERT(char(5), EndTime, 108) AS Register, 
    CourseType, Mins_Poss, Mins_Att, Mins_Late, TermTimeWeekNo, WeekStart, Class_Register, 
    Register_Title, Register_Day, StartTime, EndTime, PrimaryProgramme, 
    Lecturer_Section, Lecturer_Department
    FROM            CurrentAttendance_New
    WHERE        (RegYear = @Year) AND (LecturerName IN (@Lecturer))
    GROUP BY Lecturer_Code, LecturerName, AgeBand, RegYear, PRPH_ML1, 
    [Curriculum Area], PRPH_Title, Section, Section_Name, CourseType, Mins_Poss, Mins_Att, 
    Mins_Late, TermTimeWeekNo, WeekStart, Class_Register, Register_Title, 
    Register_Day, StartTime, EndTime, PrimaryProgramme, Lecturer_Section, 
    Lecturer_Department
    ORDER BY LecturerName, CourseType
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible?   This doesn't sound like a programming question to me.

Comment: Are your SQL queries calculating the overall attendance by Main Course and Lecturer, or does your report do the calculation? Can you show some example results rows from each query?

Comment: @Pete - I am doing calculations in my report. Sure, I will update some sample data.